# Prove that $\ \nabla f(Q_0)$ is perpendicular to $\ (P-Q)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\ f$ be differentiable in some neighborhood with $\ P$ and $\ Q$ in it such that $\ f(P)=f(Q)$, prove that there is a point $\ Q_0$ in the segment that joins $\ P$ and $\ Q$ such that $\ \nabla f(Q_0)$ is perpendicular to $\ (P-Q)$

**What I did:**

We need to prove that: $\ \nabla f(Q_0) (P-Q)=0$

Using the mean value theorem in several variables, it follows that there is a $\ Q_0$ in the segment that joins $\ P$ and $\ Q$, moreover, the next equality holds:

$\ \nabla f(Q_0) (P-Q)=f(P)-f(Q)$

But, since $\ f(P)=f(Q)$ then $\ f(P)-f(Q)=0$, so:

$\ \nabla f(Q_0) (P-Q)=0$, therefore, $\ \nabla f(Q_0)$ is perpendicular to $\ (P-Q)$.

Question is, what would be a good aproach to the problem if I didn't knew of the existence of the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reprove the MVT, or apply Rolle's theorem from Calculus 101 to the auxiliary function
$$\phi(t):=f\bigl((1-t)P+t Q\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
I'm afraid there is no way around the MVT somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Althought is not rigorous, you can try to argue geometrically: exploit the geometrical meaning of the gradient, figure out the segment $P-Q$ and use the hypotesis $f(P)=f(Q)$.

A second way I would try would be to reason by contradiction.